# Arduino IDE: Error resolving FQBN: getting

Tags: arduino

In Arduino IDE 1.8.19, I get this error "Error resolving FQBN: getting", when compiling a sketch. Can anyone help me get around this problem?

I am using the Arduino IDE v1.8.19. I have installed the M5Stack official 2.0.5-1.0 boards in Board Manager and the STAMP-PICO 0.0.2 library in Library Manager.

I get the following Compile error with ALL sketches, even the STAMP-PICO Basics IO example sketch.

"Error resolving FQBN: getting
Error compiling for board STAMP-PICO."

Strangely ... in Arduino IDE v2.0.3, on the same computer using the same libraries and boards, the sketch compiles ok.

Sounds like something specific to Arduino IDE v1

Answer (score 0):

OK - I resolved the issue, myself.

The Boards Manager installations became confused, probably because I was using both Arduino 1.8.19 and Arduino IDE 2.0.3 on the same computer.

Somehow, the folder ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/m5stack/hardware/esp32/ contained more than one version of the esp32 board libraries, v2.0.5 as well as v2.0.5-1.0 and c2.0.5+1.0.

My fix involved uninstalling the M5 esp32 board library altogether and making sure that all sub-folder versions had been deleted too. Then, reinstalling the latest board version and restarting the Arduino IDE app.